# Python like json parsing in Scala ?

Tags: json, scala

Coming from python background I find it hard to parse JSON properly in Scala(Especially when JSON don't follow a specific schema).

Python parses JSON with ease and you can iterate through elements using `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` etc.

Is there any good JSON library in Scala, which can parse JSON without having to define a `case class`. This seems extremely painful if we have nested JSON.

I tried Gson and Json4s both of them requires many case class to reflect JSON to a scala object...Can we parse and extract values without doing all of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/) is great library. It has excellent facilities for defining codecs, traversing JSON and parsing JSON.

This example (from the documentation) shows parsing without defining a case class:

```
package argonaut.doc

import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

object ParseExample extends App {

  val json = """
    { "name" : "Toddler", "age" : 2, "greeting": "gurgle!" }
  """

  // Parse getting either error message or json
  val result: String \/ Json =
    Parse.parse(json)

  // Parse ignoring error messages
  val option: Option[Json] =
    Parse.parseOption(json)

  // Parse handling success and failure with functions
  val greeting1: String =
    Parse.parseWith(json, _.field("greeting").flatMap(_.string).getOrElse("Hello!"), msg => msg)

  // Parse handling success and providing a default for failure
  val greeting2: String =
    Parse.parseOr(json, _.field("greeting").flatMap(_.string)getOrElse("Hello!"), "Oi!")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `lift` json library. Add this in your in `build.sbt`:

`"net.liftweb" %% "lift-json-scalaz" % "3.0-M1"`

Then in your code for example:

```
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats
object test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        //This is used to map the JSON string to a object in Scala. The constructor parameters have to match the keys in the JSON object.
        case class PersonObject (name: String, Age: String)

        implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

        val jsonString = """ { "name":"Bob", "Age":"14" } """
        val parsedJson = parse(jsonString)
        val extractedInJsonObject = parsedJson.extract[PersonObject]
        val name = extractedInJsonObject.name
    } 

}
```

This is the example above if you want to use the lift JSON library. To find more information look at this documentation:
https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json

This part of the documentation might be useful for you:
https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json#extracting-values

If your JSON has a nested object:

```
{
  "name" : "Bob",
  "age": "15",
  "address" : {
     "street" : "miller avenue",
     "city" : "San Francisco"
  }
}
```

Then your case class should look like this:

```
case class Address(street: String, city: String)
case class Person(name: String, age: String, address: Address)
```

Usually you would have to use a case class you really don't have another choice. If you do find another way please let me know!